# Flutter: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log in with two different types on flutter firebase. I tried too many things but still, I couldn't do it. In the end, I found another solution but I got new errors.

> Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform that does not exist.

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
          
          return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(snapshot.data!.uid).snapshots() ,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                final userDoc = snapshot.requireData;
                // final user = userDoc.data();
                if(userDoc.get('role') == 'admin') {
                  return AdminPage();
                }else{
                  return Home();
                }
              }else{
                return Material(
                  child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
                );
              }
            },
          );
        }
        return LoginPage();
      }
    );
```

I'm doing an app with two logins. Patients and doctors. Doctors can control patients or smth like that. So doctors should be admins. I made two login options. Admin login and user login. But if I can do it on the same login page, it would be good.

Comment: Do you have an auth checker page? That may be simpler to do the redirect logic

Comment: Nope.Im actually using this page as an auth.To direct it when i open the app.

Comment: body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Home();
          } else
            return LoginPage();    It was the original.But when i login as an admin in these codes, it directed to the patients home page.

Comment: Seems complicated to have a streambuilder determine at least imo. I think that should be determined before a streamBuilder is implemented